# Ceph Lumonius Bluestore Performance Issue and Trim? Discard?

Tags: ceph

Good morning..

I'm testing the Ceph Luminous version.

The first RBD Good performance at 1TB SSD X 9OSD (3OSD_Node), 1250MB / s (10G Network)

As well.

However, after filling the entire storage capacity(100%) of the Cluster, the performance drops to 200MB / s at 20% after the RBD deletion. What is the problem?

There was no such problem when tested with FileStore (XFS) as above.

TRIM? Discard?

I am currently operating Jewel, Kraken.

Comment: What brand/type of SSDs are you using?

Comment: Thank you..Samsung SSD 850 Pro / 1TB

Comment: https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-850-pro-2-5-sata-iii-1tb-mz-7ke1t0bw/

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't support for Trim/Discard functionality in mainline Ceph Luminous. https://github.com/ceph/ceph/pull/14727

Comment: Thank you.
The link is a link I've seen before, and it's been done more since then.
I did not even wonder if this feature was really excluded.

I have to wait for the patch to be formally released.